# Create and move terms for taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy, terms, front-end

I'm trying to create a front end taxonomy and term interface.

I currently have:

```
<form id="updatetax" method="post">
    <input name="term_name" type="text" value="">

    <select name="tax_selection">
    <?php $taxonomies   = get_object_taxonomies( 'cpt_taxonomy', 'objects' ); ?>

        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <?php
            foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $taxonomy->name . '">' . $taxonomy->label . '</option>';
            }

        ?>
    </select>

    <!-- I have a hidden input with the term ID and the current taxonomy if updating -->
    <input name="termID" value="<?php echo $_GET['termID']; ?>">
    <input name="currentTax" value="<?php echo $_GET['currentTax']; ?>">
</form>
```

Then in the submission, I get the fields and try to update the term:

```
<?php
    $term_args = array(
        'name'      => $_POST['term_name'],
        'taxonomy'  => $_POST['tax_selection'],
        'term_id'   => $_POST['termID']
    );

    wp_update_term( $_POST['termID'], $_POST['currentTax'], $term_args );

?>
```

In the codex it seemed that's all was needed to do to update the term. However, though I can get the title to update, I cannot seem to get the taxonomy to change and update.

I was wondering what I am doing wrong. My end goal to it be able to move/update the terms between taxonomies, add new ones from the form above (by selecting the taxonomy in the select field), and add custom term meta.

Comment: Do you want to change the taxonomy or an existing term ? Or create a term for an existing taxonomy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_update_term()` doesn't changes taxonomy. It just updated the existing taxonomy. Say the below code-

```
$update = wp_update_term( 1, 'category', array(
    'name' => 'Uncategorized Renamed',
    'slug' => 'uncategorized-renamed'
) );

if ( ! is_wp_error( $update ) ) {
    echo 'Success!';
}
```

This code finds the category which ID is 1, then updates it to the name and slug passed by as a parameter. In the context of my system the category with ID 1 is Uncategorized. So it will rename it.

For changing terms taxonomy there is no default function. Here I've written one for you. Take a look below-

```
function the_dramatist_change_terms_taxonomy( $term_id, $future_taxonomy ){
    global $wpdb;
    $update = $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy',
        [ 'taxonomy' => $future_taxonomy ],
        [ 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term_id ],
        [ '%s' ],
        [ '%d' ]
    );
    return $update;
}
```

Here `$term_id` is the term's ID which taxonomy you wanna change and `$future_taxonomy` is the terms future taxonomy. `$future_taxonomy` must have to be string like **'category'**, **'post_tag'** or **'any_other_taxonomy'**. **It actually updates the database value directly. So be careful before you use it.** Specially careful if your term has any parent. Cause it is basically updating the taxonomy value at `wp_terms_taxonomy` table, not any other one. For updating terms taxonomy I've not found any better option.

And for inserting terms to a taxonomy you can use `wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() )`. So you can check that if desired taxonomy is exist or not. If it exists then update it, if it is not then create it. Like below-

```
$term = term_exists( 'Uncategorized', 'category' );
if ( $term !== 0 && $term !== null ) {
    the_dramatist_change_terms_taxonomy( $term->term_id, $future_taxonomy )
} else {
    wp_insert_term( '...All..The...Parameter..Here' );
}
```

Comment: I just realised that the function stopped working. I updated the term_taxonomy_id to be just term_id and it is working. Is it a typo?

Comment: Yes. It's the name of a column in the table `wp_term_taxonomy`.  You must not change this.

Comment: This works. FYI, though - if, like me, you fire this on the `create_term` action, so as to immediately move a term when a user adds it via "Add New Tag" in the back-end, the "Add New Tag" page refreshes with an error notice. The move (ie. from "post_tag" to "category" actually completes successfully - but WordPress is unable to refresh the starting page to show the newly-created post_tag, so it throws an error.

Comment: In your function you'd pass the `$term_id`, but then that is assigned to the `term_taxonomy_id` key. Do you mean to pass `$term_taxonomy_id` to the function and *not* the `$term_id`? (My experience is limited, but I've never seen these two tag object keys differ. They're always the same number).