# Cannot delete or edit a single term in a custom taxonomy, taxonomy name is wrong?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I have created a custom taxonomy with the basic code below. I created a term called 'video' some time ago to test it. I created a few other terms today then noticed that I cannot delete or edit that first created term 'video'. It is grayed out and offers only the view link, which is a broken link. Oddly, using the correct permalink structure, the page for the 'video' term does display as expected.

I can create and edit other terms without any errors. There's also no errors anywhere else in the WP admin pages.

UPDATE:

After troubleshooting, I believe the issue is because I initially created the custom taxonomy with the name `Purpose`, but then changed it to `purpose`. Calling `$object->taxonomy` returns `Purpose`, while all the others listed in the admin panel return `purpose`.

How can I change this term's taxonomy from `Purpose` to `purpose`?

Here is the function that creates the taxonomy:

```
function post_purpose_taxonomy()
{
    $args = array (
        'labels' => array('name' => 'Purpose Tags', 'singular_name' => 'Purpose Tag'),
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy('purpose', [ 'post', 'dvposts' ], $args);
}
add_action('init', 'post_purpose_taxonomy');
```

You can see that I register the taxonomy to both posts and the custom post type 'dvposts'.

Here is a snapshot:

[image: Cannot delete or edit a single term in a custom taxonomy]

Comment: This is unusual, but, I notice your `register_taxonomy` call is very small, normally there are a lot more options declared. I also notice that you make an extra call to `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` rather than just passing `[ 'post', 'dvposts' ]` as the second parameter. Have you disabled all plugins and confirmed that none of them cause this? Or that this still happens in a blank clean slate WP install with the default theme and that code?

Comment: @TomJNowell This is a clean install and a custom theme from scratch. I'll try passing `[ 'post', 'dvposts' ]` in `register_taxonomy` instead and see what happens.

Comment: @TomJNowell Tried `register_taxonomy('purpose', [ 'post', 'dvposts' ], $args);` and removed `register_taxonomy_for_object_type`. That did not work. Also just tried passing `'capabilities' => array ('manage_terms','edit_terms','delete_terms','assign_terms')` and no luck.

Comment: Activating the 2020 WP theme removes the custom taxonomy. Are you suggesting registering the custom taxonomy in the 2020 WP theme for testing?

Comment: Register the theme in a single file plugin that has nothing else, then see if this happens in a fresh WP install. As for the other array suggestion that wasn't to fix your issue else I'd have written it as a full answer rather than a comment

Comment: I copy pasted your code into a fresh plugin and tried to reproduce your problem, and failed. I could not recreate the problem. Your problem is caused by something else that isn't mentioned in your question. You will need to identify the cause via a process of elimination

Comment: Here is the plugin I created to test your code: https://gist.github.com/tomjn/6c0c162a0662c8cc2e3a53f0bbfb901d Remember, you should not register taxonomies and post types in themes, it's very bad practice. Do it in plugins instead. Also keep in mind that what you're seeing in the screenshot is not normal WP, something has done that. There is no way to configure WP out of the box to make a term look like that

Comment: @tom Thank you. I'm still a novice with WP, so really appreciate the time. I'll try the plugin suggestion on Monday. Happy 4th.

Comment: Just keep iin mind that plugin won't fix your problem, I don't know the cause or the solution ot your issue, I'm just suggesting best practices and debugging techniques to try and help identify what's going on

Comment: @TomJNowell I've finally had a chance to crack at this again. I've had no luck repeating the issue on a clean install and have fiddled for many hours with the $args, but have not been able to get anything to change on that one term called "video". I was able to get all kinds of changes on the rest, as you'd expect, but nothing made "video" editable. Should I be considering a dive into the db tables now?

Answer (score 1):

### Credit for this answer goes entirely to CodeMascot:
[Create and move terms for taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/243693/38365)

After troubleshooting, I believe the issue is because I initially created the custom taxonomy with the name `Purpose`, but then changed it to `purpose` at another time. Calling `$object->taxonomy` returns `Purpose` on the affected term, while all the others listed in the admin panel return `purpose`.

I strongly suspect that the taxonomy originally starting with a capital letter created a privileges issue, probably related to some to-lower-case method because some privileges were allowed. Once the taxonomy names matched perfectly, all issues were resolved.

After my troubleshooting determined that the taxonomy key of the term was incorrect, the question then became "How to change an existing term's taxonomy key"? The answer is that you must access the powerful and risky `global $wpdb`. This variable allows you to access and write the WordPress database directly. I added the following to the functions.php file, then refreshed a page two or three times, and the issue was resolved.

```
function the_dramatist_change_terms_taxonomy( $term_id, $future_taxonomy ){
    global $wpdb;
    $update = $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->prefix . 'term_taxonomy',
        [ 'taxonomy' => $future_taxonomy ],
        [ 'term_taxonomy_id' => $term_id ],
        [ '%s' ],
        [ '%d' ]
    );
    return $update;
}

the_dramatist_change_terms_taxonomy(26,'purpose');
```

Now that the change has been made, I have removed the function from the functions.php file and `$object->taxonomy` returns `purpose`.

Comment: You might want to adjust the answer as it doesn't make make sense on its own, a user coming across this won't understand what changing a terms taxonomy has to do with the grayed out term in the question

Comment: @TomJNowell Better?

Comment: Better but best to  move  the extra  bit added to the very top